# PHP exec command works from terminal but not from web

Tags: php, unix, exec, solaris, scp

I created a simple test file lets call it exec.php with this content:

```
<?php
    exec('scp -r /vhosts/malta/docs/www/mysite/uploads/www.mysite.com/images/promotions/xmas-survey user@255.255.255.255:/vhosts/mysite/docs/www/images/promotions/xmas-survey/',$out);
    print_r($out);
?>
Command Executed.
```

FYI: account user doesn't need a password to access 255.255.255.255

The problem is here :

when I run this file from the terminal like

```
php /vhosts/test/www/exec.php
```

the command works but when i try to run it from the web like

```
http://localhost/test/exec.php
```

the command doesn't.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: remember that when it's running under a webserver, it's running a different user id, which means a different account, a different ssh keychain, etc... e.g. everything's completely different, except the command itself.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser/logs?

Comment: And the error messages on the secure.log or whatever authentication log on the host that you're trying to connect to shows what?  (ie, did it see the incoming connection, did it allow access?)

Comment: @Joe I'm willing to bet something that `scp` was never executed, so wouldn't expect much from there... there wouldn't be much point in keeping scp in path for the web user

Comment: Thanks Marc, will try to make sure the webserver have the necessary rights.

Will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a ssh login from the webserver to the other server for the user that runs the webserver (e.g. www-data, apache2, etc...), otherwise the scp command won't work.

once you create the ssh login the command should work...

you might want to secure the ssh login with an rsa key for better security if you haven't done that already

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. The user is specified in the command: user@255.255.255.255

Answer (score 0):

Probably what's wrong is that you need to specify full path to scp. Web server user usually doesn't have the same things in path.

To actually diagnoze what went wrong, redirect stderr to somewhere you can read it from.

As example:

```
exec($yourcommand . " 2>&1", $out);
// print out the $out variable
```

Answer (score 0):

check the user "www-data" have necessary execute permissions for running the exec.php file

Comment: The daemon user does have the rights to run exec. This has been tested with a simple ls command. 

Thanks for your input